# Converting dtype=object to binary values

Tags: python, classification, data-science

I have a dataset which has a column that contains two different texts (PAIDOFF, COLLECTION) and I want to convert it to binary values so I tried the following:

```
y = df['loan_status'].values
y[0:5]
```

Output:

```
array(['PAIDOFF', 'PAIDOFF', 'PAIDOFF', 'PAIDOFF', 'PAIDOFF'],
  dtype=object)
```

After defining the target column, tried to convert it to binary values:

```
#Convert y to binary values
le_loan_status=preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
le_loan_status.fit(['PAIDOFF','COLLECTION'])
y[:,0]= le_loan_status.transform(y[:,0])
```

Output:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-917e44b54b88> in <module>
      2 le_loan_status=preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
      3 le_loan_status.fit(['PAIDOFF','COLLECTION'])
----> 4 y[:,0]= le_loan_status.transform(y[:,0])

IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 1-dimensional, but 2 were indexed
```

Do you have any idea to solve this?

Comment: pd.get_dummies(df["loan_status"],drop_first=True) ?

Comment: worked like a charm. thanks for quick help

Comment: i tried it in another project but this time i get this : 'IndexError: only integers, slices' '(`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid' 'indices'

Comment: show a screenshot of your code on the main question

Comment: my bad, forgot to change array names. thanks again. If u add it as a solution, i can approve it

Comment: done already, good luck with ur code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Converting to dummies***

```
dummies = pd.get_dummies(df["loan_status"],drop_first=True) 

new_data = pd.concat([df,dummies],axis=1)
```

[Docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html)